# Enterprise wiki site collection VS wiki library

Tags: publishing-site, wiki, architecture, enterprise-wiki, information-management

I am in a point to decide which approach I should follow for building a wiki site for our company , the wiki need to have the following features:

- Create wiki pages and add related metadata info. This metadata info includes such things as the built-in wiki category in addition to other columns.
- Enable metadata navigation and filtering, to be able to click on certain terms and get the related wiki pages.

Now I cannot decide which approach to follow, either:

1. Create new site collection of type Enterprise wiki.
2. Or inside my current team site to just add a wiki library?

From my own testing, I found the following differences:

1. Inside the enterprise wiki site collection, you can add the metadata info such as the built-in wiki category on the same page when you add/edit the wiki page body, while in the wiki page library case you have to edit the wiki page properties to add the related metadata.
2. Both approaches allow metadata navigation and filtering and creating wiki pages from other pages by typing [[pagename]].
3. One of the main differences is that if I enable “mobile view” feature , then I can view the wiki library pages inside the mobile devices in a mobile friendly manner, while in the enterprise wiki site collection the wiki page body will be rendered as a white empty section. Not sure if there is a way to fix this in the enterprise wiki, but for me this is a big advantage for the wiki library over enterprise wiki site collection, which is mobile view support.

Answer (score 3):

John,

I found a few helpful links on comparing the two options. I think the most important difference you may want to consider is the metadata implementation. The library option looks to be more restrictive.

> While you can manually add metadata to Wiki Page Library, you can’t add the fields to the text layouts. This means users would have to edit the content of the page, then separately edit the properties of the page to enter metadata, which is not good for encouraging metadata entry.

[Differences between Enterprise Wiki and Wiki Page Library in SharePoint 2013](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/05/10/differences-between-enterprise-wiki-and-wiki-page-library-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Some other things to consider and what Microsoft suggest based on what you may want to accomplish.

[image: Comparison of Enterprise Wikis with Team Sites]

[Comparison of Enterprise Wikis with Team Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721051.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply, i already read these links, and i found that Enterprise Wiki site collection is more powerful if we want to build an enterprise repository for all our info including images, pages, videos, etc. so Enterprise-wiki provides more features, but the only thing i can not find an answer to it is why Enterprise-wiki pages do not show when i enable "Mobile view" feature ?? as if i enable this site feature and i access an enterprise wiki page from my mobile, the enterprise-wiki page content will be displayed as a blank white page .... not sure if this is a bug in SP ?

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer using a team site and use existing site features and apps to get the same effect that a specialized site template gives you, excluding the very specialized things like records center, video portal, etc.

You said it yourself, mobile is key, they both methods create content the same way, both can have mmetadata navigation and filtering, and the only difference is how the metadata tagging is done, which isn't really a big deal and is easily overcome with communication. People are accustomed to doing that aready with other lists and libraries.

I prefer flexibility over specialization, so I lean towards team sites as the basis for about 99% of my sites.

Comment: but do u mean that enterprise wiki site collection is not supported on mobile phones ?  i think there should be a way to fix this but could not find any ... second question from my reading is that using wiki library will limit the customization that can be done especially concerning the wiki page. for example i have been working on an enterprise wiki SC where i added many additional site columns to the wiki page, so when users create/edit a wiki page they can add the wiki page body, name, built-in wiki category, many other metadata fields from the same page.

Comment: and also when reading a wiki page all the related columns will be displayed on the right side of the page. while when using wiki library you can not modify the text layout that is provided by the wiki page. so if the main requirement for a site is to have wiki pages (for example intranet wiki site for a company) then having a dedicated enterprise wiki site collection provides more features and functionalists,, what do u think ?

Comment: Sure, these are some of the tihings you get with a specialized template, but the tradeoff is you can't do some of the other things that you want. You need to take this information and decide what is best for your needs.

Comment: so you mean that there is not any way i can fix the mobile view issue when using enterprise wiki site collection ? is this a limitation or it is a bug in SP ? i think  it looks more as a bug somehwere rather than a limitation, becuase sharepoint will be rendering a mobile view for the enterprose wiki site collection ,, but the wiki body will be rendered as a blank white page.. if this was a limitation then the whole mobile view will not be shown, or the "mobile browser view" site feature will not be avilable inside enterprise wiki site colleciton,which is not the case, what do you think ?

Comment: idk honestly, we're just getting into 2013 and i've rarely used that site template

Comment: @Erix Alexander strange what is going on ,,, i reported this to issue to the SharePoint team on Microsoft msdn but without getting any reply. someone just reply that rich text editor is not supported on mobile devices,, but i mentioned that the wiki is not showing correctly even on  the view mode not on the edit mode !! also inside wiki library the wiki page will be viewed correctly on mobile devices and it use rich text also!

Comment: i am totally confused as i was going to chose enterprise wiki SC because i use it before and i can do extra modification not available inside the wiki library, but can not decide if i will be able to fix its problem on mobile devices or not ??